# In multi-class logistic regression, does SGD one training example update all the weights?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-science, gradient-descent

In multi-class logistic regression, lets say we use softmax and cross entropy.
Does SGD one training example update all the weights or only a portion of the weights which are associated to the label ?
For example, the label is one-hot `[0,0,1]`
Does the whole matrix `W_{feature_dim \times num_class}` updated or only `W^{3}_{feature_dim \times 1}` updated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of your weights are updated.

You have **y** = Softmax(**W** **x** + **β**), so to predict a **y** out of a single **x** you are making use of all your W weights. If something is used during the forward pass (prediction), then it also gets updated during the backward pass (SGD). Perhaps a more intuitive way of thinking about it is that you are essentially predicting the class membership probability for your features; assigning weight to some class means removing weight from another, so you need to update both.

Take for instance the simple case of **x** ∈ ℝ, **y** ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup>. Then **W** ∈ ℝ<sup>1×3</sup>. Before activation, your prediction for some given **x** would look like: **y**= [**y**<sub>1</sub> = **W**<sub>11</sub>**x** + **β**<sub>1</sub>, **y**<sub>2</sub> = **W**<sub>12</sub>**x** + **β**<sub>2</sub>, **y**<sub>3</sub> = **W**<sub>13</sub>**x** + **β**<sub>3</sub>]. You have an error signal for all of these mini-predictions, coming out of categorical crossentropy, for which you must then compute the derivative wrt the **W**, **β** terms.

I hope this is clear